# Incoming offtopic questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, vote-to-close

I do not if I am just in bad mood or what, but it seems to me:

- there is unusual volume of offtopic questions incoming recently
- too little people are closing them or at least downvoting them

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/do-languages-become-simpler-only-because-of-the-need-for-easier-collaboration

[Can any fish climb trees?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/are-all-fish-incapable-of-climbing-trees)

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5361/why-do-power-lines-buzz

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/can-we-see-the-curvature-of-earth-from-the-top-of-worlds-tallest-building

I think all of them share one in common: while the question may be interesting or fun (esp. the last one was for me), the claim they want to check is by no means notable. Do we want such question to exist here? Will they, in long term, do more harm or good to the site?

Comment: -1 The fish quote had 300K google hits.

Comment: Uf. Yes, the quote is well known, but the quote was not a real claim. The questions takes literally something that was never meant as such. See comment for the question as Chad "Actually its not a claim that fish are incapable of doing it, just that it is not reasonable to judge them by a criteria that is irrelevant to being a fish." Do you want us to research other well known sayings, like "there is no smoke without fire" (7M google hits)?

Comment: 1) What does "Uf." mean? 2) If I thought that that saying was spreading false knowledge, I would do exactly that.

Comment: 1) Uf means oof. It is a sound which Indians make as a sign of utmost surprise in westerns.  2) Can you document a notable instance when someone was taking the claim "fish incapable of climing trees" literally, spreading the false knowlegde that way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's widely understood that questions should have a certain level of notability.

However, I also think that asking for references if you are unsure that the claim is actually a real notable claim is something the community should do, as well as down voting irrelevant questions and voting to close.

The problem is not that there is bad quality content coming our way. That's going to happen more and more as we grow and appear in google searches more frequently (for example). The problem in my opinion is that *not enough people are helping the moderators*.

- **Down vote** content which is not good. Questions AND answers. It is shameful that bad questions and answers have sometimes 10+ up votes. They should have -10 votes.
- **Vote to close** stuff which is off topic or actively bad for us.
- **Flag** answers without references as not an answer. They are NOT answers. Each question has the hidden implied statement "I will only accept answers which are based on facts and experiment"
- **Ask for references in comments** for questions and answers. Mods and 3/4 users shouldn't be the only ones doing it. There are 4000 users on this site and you only need 10 rep to comment.

For this site to work and scale with size, **everybody** has to do that. Moderators should be only handling edge cases, not doing the bulk of content sorting because not enough users help.

It's not a random choice that you have a [review page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review) and a [tools page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tools) available. Use them. Help us moderate massively and make this site scale up with size!